# How to create alert according to newrelic error logs

Tags: java, alert, newrelic, agent

I have a Java application running in a microservices architecture. I collect the logs and error conditions of the services on the New Relic platform using the New Relic agent. I want to create alarms through the New Relic platform based on error logs. These alarms should be mostly unique for similar error logs and should include the error stack in the alert notification. I'm not sure how to define alarms and use correlation decisions to achieve this goal. I would appreciate it if you could help.

I have created simple alarms, but each issue that is currently triggered includes recent errors. This means that one issue can contain multiple errors or no errors at all.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the alert only counts 1 because the default 'window duration' is 1 minute. When the query may find 11, because the default query duration is 60 minutes.

To solve this: you can increase the window duration to 1h. however (unless using threshold type 'at least once in') this may delay your alert significantly.

Ideally, you need to review the correct 'window duration' needed to have sufficient events to consider that an outage worthy of being notified is happening. This will vary for all use cases.

In order to troubleshoot issues like these, you can review what the alert is evaluating by querying select * from NrAiSignal where conditionId =